# Finitely generated group quasi-isometric to finitely presented group

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be finitely presented and let $H$ be finitely generated such that $G$ is quasi-isometric to $H$. Show that $H$ is finitely presented.

I am not 100% certain about the definition of quasi-isometry for groups, I believe we can take it to mean that their Cayley graphs are quasi-isometric (which I'm fine with, since I know how to show that if $S_1$, $S_2$ two finite generating sets of $G$ then $\Gamma(S_1 , G)$ is quasi-isometric to $\Gamma(S_2, G)$).

I started by writing $G$ as $\langle S \mid R\rangle$, and letting $T$ be a finite generating set of $H$. Let $f\colon G\to H$ be a $(K,A)$-quasi-isometry. I note that any $h\in H$ is at most a distance $L$ from $f(v)$ for some $v\in G$ ($L$ a positive constant independent of $h$).

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What book are you reading? The problem you are trying to solve is a standard but nontrivial result.

Comment: If you are not even sure about definitions, this problem will be way too hard for you. My suggestion is to focus on easier staff.

Comment: I am working from lecture notes on a course in geometric group theory at my college. I have taken the prerequisite courses and am happy with the content before this exercise.

I know what is meant by a quasi-isometry, net, geodesic metric space, I can prove Milnor-Svarc lemma. I can prove that if $G$ finitely generated and $S_1$, $S_2$ finite generating sets then $\Gamma(S_1, G)$ quasi-isometric to $\Gamma(S_2, G)$; that $G$ is quasi-isometric to finite index $H\leq G$; and that $G$ is quasi-isometric to $G/N$ for finite normal $N$.

Comment: Then, likely, you are not ready for this problem.

Comment: I know what is meant by quasi-isometry for metric spaces, and I can associate to each $G$ a finitely generated group and $S\subseteq G$ a finite generating set two metric spaces: the Cayley graph $\Gamma (S,G)$, and the subspace $G$ of vertices. The lecture notes do not specify which of these two should be taken when defining quasi-isometry for groups.

Comment: If I remember it correctly, you will find proofs in the books by Geoghegan and by Drutu and Kapovich. But you will need to learn tools that you do not currently have.

Comment: Then, look in her book.

Comment: I would appreciate a hint. The exercise follows immediately after the results I mentioned above. Her book is more than 10 times longer than the lecture notes of the course I am taking, on which I am sitting an exam in a couple of weeks. I am also sitting several other exams, so I'm not sure I have the time to go through her entire book. If anyone could help at all, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does tell you that you have to read the whole book to understand the proof? it's definitely part of introduction to research to be able to find the relevant part of a proof in a textbook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read section "Connectivity and coarse connectivity" in Chapter 9 of

*Druţu, Cornelia; Kapovich, Michael*, [**Geometric group theory. With an appendix by Bogdan Nica**](https://doi.org/10.1090/coll/063), Colloquium Publications. American Mathematical Society 63. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-1-4704-1104-6/hbk; 978-1-4704-4164-7/ebook). xx, 819 p. (2018). [ZBL1447.20001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1447.20001).

The proof of the result you are asked to prove is there.

Of course, some of this material might be covered in your lecture notes, I have no way to tell.

Alternatively, read Theorem 18.2.12 (for groups of type $F_2$) in

*Geoghegan, Ross*, [**Topological methods in group theory**](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/129610), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 243. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-74611-1/hbk). xiv, 473 p. (2008). [ZBL1141.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1141.57001).